# Salvar cookie quando faz um clique dentro de uma DIV

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

Tenho uma DIV, nela vai anúncios.. e quero que crie um cookie de 2 dias.. Ou seja, Antes de carregar a pagina ele verifica se já clicou em alguma lugar da DIV nos últimos 2 dias, se já clicou ele aparece outra coisa no lugar do anuncio..

mas tenho que capturar esse cookie com PHP usando IF como o código abaixo.

```html
<?php if ($cookie === sim): ?>
  JA CLICOU
<?php else: ?>
  AINDA N CLICOU
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: a melhor maneira que vejo isso acontecendo seria usando `jQuery`, assim voce pode fazer uma requisicao `ajax`  `jQuery.get`  `jQuery.post` onde voce trata o click do user, quando voce recarregar a pagina voce consulta a cookie via php e passa o valor para o html. ta usando algum framework? tem muitas maneira de fazer isso, seria interessante voce postar algo sobre seu projeto assim como o codigo ja existente

Comment: Quero fazer um protetor de link.. atualmente soh com bootstrap

Comment: Nos códigos dos links acima tem tanto referência de como setar um cookie com PHP (incluso duração), quanto como recuperar um cookie com PHP. Caso ainda assim persista a dúvida, queira [edit] sua questão focando na parte específica do que já sabe/tentou e de qual parte exatamente é sua dúvida ou dificuldade. Caso não tenha solução no site, o post pode ser reaberto. Ou se encontrou a solução, mas tem alguma dúvida não coberta pela pergunta, pode deixar um comentário também.

Comment: Como setar eu sei! eu ja tenho um código pronto de como setar.. eu soh não sei como setar esse cookies so quando clicar em uma div!